# How to read the sensitive parameter value in SSIS script task?

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, ssis-2016

In my SSIS package, I need to use a password parameter and I would like to keep it as sensitive. Is there a way to read this sensitive parameter value in the script task?

I tried to use the `GetSensitiveValue()` method as in [this](https://www.hansmichiels.com/2016/11/19/using-sensitive-parameters-ssis-series/) link but it always returns an empty string.

[image: Image of parameters in visual studio]

Adding the code below

```
Variables varCollection = null;


Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::Username");
Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("$Package::Password");
Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCol);


var username = varCollection["User::Username"].Value.ToString();
var password = varCollection["$Package::Password"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();
```

Are there any other ways to read the sensitive parameter value?

Comment: Show your code and how you're starting the package because that method works

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29018507/181965

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the response. I have added the code and a image of the parameters to this post.

Comment: `varCollection["$Package::Password"].GetSensitiveValue.ToString()` is not the same as `varCollection["$Package::Password"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString()` Also, since you have specified the Required is True for the package, showing the design-time parameters doesn't help as you will need to specify them at run-time (which allows us to reproduce your error condition). Obviously, don't tell us the real password but showing how the package is invoked will help provide a minimal reproduction of the error.

Comment: @billinkc GetSensitiveValue without () was a typo, I corrected that in the post. . The username, password and other package parameters are stored in the SSIS Environment variables. The package will be invoked from a stored procedure.